# Two way binding to a Datagrid with a list in a new window

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, data-binding, datagrid

I am having some issues with databinding a list to a datagrid. My code is as follows.

I want to bind my observable collection;

```
        ObservableCollection<RectangleContour> rectContourList = new ObservableCollection<RectangleContour>();
```

of RectangleContour Objects;

```
        public class RectangleContour : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public int Property1{ get; set; }
        public int Property2{ get; set; }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        // This method is called by the Set accessor of each property. 
        // The CallerMemberName attribute that is applied to the optional propertyName 
        // parameter causes the property name of the caller to be substituted as an argument. 
        private void NotifyPropertyChanged( String propertyName = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to bind the list to a datagrid view that exists in another window that is called from the window the above objects belong to, I call the new window like this;

```
                Window window = new Window
            {
                Title = "My User Control Dialog",
                Content = new UserControl1(list1: rectContourList),
            };
            window.ShowDialog();
            window.Close();
```

The data shows up correctly, and if i edit a tuple that exists already on the grid the change is reflected in my MainWindow like how I want it, however I also want to be able to add new objects through the datagrid, and when I try to do this I get an exception on the window.close() like that says I require Path or xPath to TwoWay Bind.

Can anyone point me in the right direction as to why this is occurring? do I need to set up a databinding between the two windows as well as between the datagrid and observable collection perhaps?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using this class instead of a simple list might help in your case :

```
public class ObservableListSource<T> : ObservableCollection<T>, IListSource 
        where T : class 
    { 
        private IBindingList _bindingList; 

        bool IListSource.ContainsListCollection { get { return false; } } 

        IList IListSource.GetList() 
        { 
            return _bindingList ?? (_bindingList = this.ToBindingList()); 
        } 
    }
```

**EDIT :**

In case you want to track changes of your model for example in disconnected mode the following class comes really handy :

```
  public class EditableList<TModel> : ObservableList<TModel>
        where TModel : class, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        #region Properties

        public List<TModel> EditedItems { get; set; }
        public List<TModel> AddedItems { get; set; }
        public List<TModel> DeletedItems { get; set; }

        public Boolean HasChanged
        {
            get
            {
                return
                (
                    this.EditedItems.Count > 0 ||
                    this.AddedItems.Count > 0 ||
                    this.DeletedItems.Count > 0
                );
            }

        }
        #endregion

        #region Constructor
        public EditableList(IList<TModel> list)
            : base(list)
        {
            this.AddedItems = new List<TModel>();
            this.EditedItems = new List<TModel>();
            this.DeletedItems = new List<TModel>();

            this.CollectionChanged += EditableList_CollectionChanged;

            foreach (var item in list)
                item.PropertyChanged += TModelEditableList_PropertyChanged;
        }
        public EditableList() : this(new List<TModel>()) { }


        #endregion

        #region Events
        void TModelEditableList_PropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (!(sender is TModel))
                return;

            var entity = (TModel)sender;

            this.AddToEditedItems(entity);

        }

        void EditableList_CollectionChanged(object sender, System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Action == System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add)
                foreach (TModel entity in e.NewItems)
                {
                    this.AddToAddedItems(entity);
                }

            else if (e.Action == System.Collections.Specialized.NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove)
                foreach (TModel entity in e.OldItems)
                {
                    this.AddToDeletedItems(entity);
                }
        }

        #endregion

        #region Methods
        public void AddToEditedItems(TModel entity)
        {
            if (!this.EditedItems.Contains(entity) && !this.AddedItems.Contains(entity))
                this.EditedItems.Add(entity);
        }
        public void AddToAddedItems(TModel entity)
        {
            this.AddedItems.Add(entity);
            entity.PropertyChanged += TModelEditableList_PropertyChanged;
        }
        public void AddToDeletedItems(TModel entity)
        {
            if (this.EditedItems.Contains(entity))
            {
                this.EditedItems.Remove(entity);
                this.DeletedItems.Add(entity);
            }
            else if (this.AddedItems.Contains(entity))
                this.AddedItems.Remove(entity);
            else
                this.DeletedItems.Add(entity);
        }
        public void ClearEditHistory()
        {
            this.EditedItems.Clear();
            this.AddedItems.Clear();
            this.DeletedItems.Clear();
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the reply but I do not fully understand this possible solution, are you suggesting replacing rectContourList  with your first class? How does the second class help in this situation? Can you explain more the methodology of this solution so I can understand how to implement it better? Thanks for your time.

Comment: @user4853750 Of course my friend. Yes the first class should be used for binding your datagrid. (dataGridview1.DataSource=...)The second class keeps track of your changes in the DataGrid and save them in three separate lists. It's so useful for working disconnected. I mean when you want to keep the chanages and saving them later.